# How many different ways do we have to encrypt a message?

Tags: combinatorics

I'm trying to answer this question.
We want to exchange encrypted messages. A message consists of 12 different characters and the encryption method consists of adding a total of 45 white spaces to the message. Knowing that between any of the 12 characters and the next one there must be at least 3 white spaces, how many ways is it possible to encrypt a message to be sent?

Having a string of 12 characters, I have a total of 11 spaces between one character and another that I have to fill with white spaces to encrypt the message. Knowing that there must be at least 3 white spaces between one character and the next, I have $45-33=12$ spaces to distribute as I wish. So: ${22}\choose{12}$ ways to encrypt a message. Is my reasoning correct?

Comment: Where did the $22$ in ${22\choose 12}$ come from?

Comment: @5xum $12+11-1$

Comment: @PCNF Sorry, I misread your answer earlier. You answer seems correct